# How to access data from Wikipedia OpenSearch API which is in JSON format?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, wikipedia-api

For eg here is a `JSON`

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&format=jsonfm&search=Robert&limit=6&suggest=1&redirects=return

Consisting of array of array.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to change 'format=jsonfm' to 'format=json' in your query string. Then you can get data with jQuery for example:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&format=json&search=Robert&limit=6&suggest=1&redirects=return&callback=ttt",
    jsonp: "callback",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function( response ) {
        console.log( response );
    }
});
```

And you'll get your array of arrays